# How to measure CPU, MEM usage and more for a short lived process

Tags: monitoring, time, algorithms

I've got a program with some compiled sorting algorithms, and I'm trying to use top to monitor its cpu and ram usage.

Normally this would be fine, given that the process runs for a few minutes, however, the issue is that sometimes the program only runs for a few milliseconds (small dataset) and doesn't appear in the list in top.

Is there something like the time command that I could use to spawn the process and begin monitoring until it terminates (WSL2 Ubuntu)? I have several datasets to run several algorithms on in best/worst/avg sorting order to do a basic analysis on.

Comment: the `time` command would be what you want, what's wrong with it? It tells you how much CPU und wall-clock time a program used, and how much memory it had allocated (at peak), so exactly what you can observe in `top`.

Comment: Also, this sound *a lot* like you should rather use a proper benchmarking system (like google benchmark) than some home-grown vague observational system. (The numbers seen in top are really not very useful on their own as benchmark, unless you can actually define well what "share of system load" *means* for performance on a multicore system that's actually a VM on a machine with per-CPU-core frequency scaling)